# Create QML component library

Tags: qt, qml, shared-libraries

I wasn't able to create and use a QML component library by following the fragmented parts of tutorials and Qt documentation, so I'm just gonna ask somebody to answer it all at once.

I want to create a single file (located in `/usr/lib/project/components.rcc`), that will include all components in `~/Project/src/components/` and their child components located in `~/Projects/src/components/insertparentcomponentname/`. I want to be able to use those components in normal QML code.

The question is, how can I create this file and how can I import components in it to use in QML?

( Using Qt Quick 2.0 and C++ with CMake on Arch Linux )

Comment: Are all of your files .qml? Or do you also have C++ files in your components?

Comment: @JarMan All QML in components. The C++ logic can stay in the app, I just want to be able to update the look of the components without updating the app

Comment: Did you try simply adding the .qrc file to your CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: You may find [aliases](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#resource-collection-files-op-op-qrc) in .qrc files to be helpful too to simplify the import path.

Comment: @Jarman I have not edited CMakeLists.txt, I used KDevelop defaults, probably shouldn't use KDevelop though. The only .qrc file I have is resources.qrc, which contains all my projects' resources. That documentation shows how I can (possibly) create a .rcc file based on a separate .qrc file but not how I can use the .rcc file in QML

Comment: Well then I would start with creating a separate .qrc file for your QML components and including any resources that they require.

Comment: Do you actually need an .rcc file? (That's something I don't have experience with.) If all you want is to be able to include QML files from a separate folder, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @JarMan I can't just include the QML files as they are compiled, and can thereby not be modified after compiling the application using the QML components